# In Ruby on Rails, what is a good way to get subclass's name in a base controller class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, controller, subclass

If both `ProductsController` and `CategoriesController` both inherit from `GenericController`, what is a good way to get the string `products` in the base class when the URL is pointing to the Products controller?  (in this case, the base class's index action is doing things that would need to use the string `products` to query the database)

`self.class.to_s` can be used, and it is `Analytics::ProductsController`, or `params[:controller]` can be used and it is `analytics/products`, so both can be used to extract the sub-class's name.  Is using one better than the other, or is a third way even better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
controller_name
```

Refer to the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/controller_name/class) for more details.